# Custom Script Editor Only Works In Edit Mode

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, web-part, script

I recently pulled some custom script off the internet that makes my headers sticky on a list. I put it in a script editor. I initially thought it didn't work, but now I noticed that the script only works when I'm in edit page mode. I used the process and script provided from here http://robertmcquaig.com/sharepoint/sharepoint-sticky-headers/

Comment: caching problem perhaps? Can you clear your browser cache and/or do a hard refresh when in display mode?

Comment: This is maybe also helpful **[SharePoint Script Editor only works in Edit Mode](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/sharepoint-script-editor-only-works-in-edit-mode/)**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the `type="text/javascript"` in the `<script>` tag references, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite/sites/yourlibrary/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://yoursite/sites/yourlibrary/StickyHeaders_v2.9BETA.js"></script>
```

Also see these posts:

[sharepoint 2013 / bootstrap.js / only working in edit mode](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52416/sharepoint-2013-bootstrap-js-only-working-in-edit-mode)

[jQuery accordion on Wiki page only works in edit mode?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123407/jquery-accordion-on-wiki-page-only-works-in-edit-mode)

Answer (score 2):

keep in mind that the script will not run when in post back, so, you have to save the page (stop editing) and then press Enter in the url address bar in your browser. Refresh with F5 may still not work!